# dpkg cannot remove old kernels. grub-probe halts

Tags: grub, dpkg

recently on a update, dpkg tried to install a new kernel and /boot ran out of space.

next boot it failed to find init image. so i rebooted, selected the previously good kernel, and tried to remove a few older ones.

now it stays there. on gpkg. pstree shows dpkg (v 1.17.5) started runparts which started grub-mkconfig (grub v 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.5) which started grub-probe.

and there it is for the last few hours.

I already tried to kill the processes, remove an even older kernel from /boot so it has some free space, and then tried again. same thing. it hangs forever on grub-probe.

anyone has any idea what is going on?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo dpkg --check`

Comment: it is all gone now (booted a external kernel and fixed everything from scratch on /boot and linux-* packages) but from what i investigated while fixing, `dpkg` showed my last-kernel version as "incomplete" and my last-kernel-1 version as OK, but it wasn't. if i used last-kernel-2 version i'd probably be able to fix things right away. Still no idea why last-kernel-1 was corrupted. but on it, things like grub-probe and even `lsusb` halted forever. Also, plugging external drivers showed the USB device on log, but no sd* device.